# Load Json Data Sql using Python

Tags: python, json, sqlite

[ERROR MESSAGE]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQm9v.jpg)I have a JSON data files which I would like to load into a database:

**JSON Data**

```
{"metadata": {"start_at": "05-08-2020 18:28:16 +000", "end_at": "06-08-2020 18:28:15 +000", "activities_count": 5}, "activities_data": [{"performed_at": "05-08-2020 18:28:16 +000", "ticket_id": 2, "performed_by": "user", "performer_id": 14720, "activity": {"note": {"id": 41607, "type": 4}}},{"performed_at": "05-08-2020 23:16:16 +000", "ticket_id": 7, "performed_by": "user", "performer_id": 14735, "activity": {"shipping_address": "N/A", "shipment_date": "", "category": "Phone", "contacted_customer": true, "issue_type": "Incident", "Source": "3", "status": "Closed", "priority": "4", "group": "refund", "agent_id": 14735, "requester": 14860, "product": "Mobile"}},{"performed_at": "06-08-2020 04:04:16 +000", "ticket_id": 5, "performed_by": "user", "performer_id": 14445, "activity": {"note": {"id": 47269, "type": 4}}},{"performed_at": "06-08-2020 08:52:16 +000", "ticket_id": 10, "performed_by": "user", "performer_id": 14344, "activity": {"shipping_address": "N/A", "shipment_date": "", "category": "Mail", "contacted_customer": false, "issue_type": "Incident", "Source": "3", "status": "Waiting for Third Party", "priority": "4", "group": "refund", "agent_id": 14344, "requester": 14950, "product": "Mobile"}},{"performed_at": "06-08-2020 13:40:16 +000", "ticket_id": 4, "performed_by": "user", "performer_id": 14946, "activity": {"note": {"id": 49575, "type": 4}}}]}
```

Now, I thinking to create a tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE if not exists stocks3
             (matchId text, region text, platformId text, matchMode text, matchType text, matchCreation text, matchDuration text, queueType text, mapId text, season text, matchVersion text, teamId text, spell1Id text, spell2Id text, championId text, highestArchivedSeasonTier text)
```

I am trying to write this code but not able to traverse thru the data inside the activities

```
import sqlite3
import json

with open('output.txt') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

for e in data:
    if e == 'activities_data':
        participants_data = data['activities_data'][0]
        print (participants_data)
        for f in participants_data:
            print (f)
            print (participants_data[f])  
    else:
        print (e)
        print (data[e])

api = data

# # let's put this in sql
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
c = conn.cursor()
#create_database
sql = 'create table if not exists tablename'
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE if not exists stocks3
             (matchId text, region text, platformId text, matchMode text, matchType text, matchCreation text, matchDuration text, queueType text, mapId text, season text, matchVersion text, teamId text, spell1Id text, spell2Id text, championId text, highestArchivedSeasonTier text)''')
conn.commit()
print(api)
c.executemany("INSERT INTO stocks3 (matchId , region , platformId , matchMode , matchType , matchCreation , matchDuration , queueType , mapId , season , matchVersion , teamId , spell1Id , spell2Id , championId , highestArchivedSeasonTier ) VALUES (:matchId,:region,:platformId,:matchMode,:matchType,:matchCreation,:matchDuration,:queueType,:mapId,:season,:matchVersion,[teamId],:spell1Id,:spell2Id,:championId,:highestArchivedSeasonTier)", api)
conn.commit()
c.execute('select * from stock3')
print(c.fetchall())

**ERROR MESSAGE**

  File "c:/Users/gusethi/Downloads/Aginic/jsonimportsample_2.py", line 29, in <module>
    c.executemany("INSERT INTO stocks3 (matchId , region , platformId , matchMode , matchType , matchCreation , matchDuration , queueType , mapId , season , matchVersion , teamId , spell1Id , spell2Id , championId , highestArchivedSeasonTier ) VALUES (:matchId,:region,:platformId,:matchMode,:matchType,:matchCreation,:matchDuration,:queueType,:mapId,:season,:matchVersion,[teamId],:spell1Id,:spell2Id,:championId,:highestArchivedSeasonTier)", api)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: teamId
```

Please if you can point me to right direction
Regards

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: well it’s not able to find teamid onwards which are part of activity block in json.

Comment: I mean, if there is an error, please post the full traceback.

Comment: teamid?  I don't see a teamid in the json data.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):  File "c:/Users/gusethi/Downloads/Aginic/jsonimportsample_2.py", line 29, in <module>    c.executemany("INSERT INTO stocks3 (matchId , region , platformId , matchMode , matchType , matchCreation , matchDuration , queueType , mapId , season , matchVersion , teamId , spell1Id , spell2Id , championId , highestArchivedSeasonTier ) VALUES (:matchId,:region,:platformId,:matchMode,:matchType,:matchCreation,:matchDuration,:queueType,:mapId,:season,:matchVersion,teamId],:spell1Id,:spell2Id,:championId,:highestArchivedSeasonTier)", api)

Comment: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: teamId
PS C:\Users\gusethi\Downloads\Aginic>

Comment: please post that in the question and not in the comment.

Comment: In addition you are only evaluating the first element of 'activities_data'.